# Is there a OWL reasoner for .NET

Tags: .net, owl, dig

I'm looking for an OWL-DL reasoner that provides an .NET API.
Alternatively I could use a DIG compliant reasoner written in any language, but
i need a .NET library that is able to convert OWL ontologies into DIG XML language.
Anyone heard about such tools/libraries?